# Non-interactively call a user defined vim script function and pass the buffer?

Tags: vimscript

How do I non-interactively call a user defined vimscript function, and pass it the buffer?

My best guess is below, but it doesn't work:

```
echo "110511093 some dude" | vim -es ':call TwiddleCase(%)' '+%print' '+:q!' /dev/stdin | cat
```

---

```
function! TwiddleCase(str)
    if a:str ==# toupper(a:str)
        let result = tolower(a:str)
    elseif a:str ==# tolower(a:str)
        let result = substitute(a:str,'\(\<\w\+\>\)', '\u\1', 'g')
    else
        let result = toupper(a:str)
    endif
     return result
endfunction
vnoremap ~ y:call setreg('', TwiddleCase(@"), getregtype(''))<CR>gv""Pgv
```

Comment: Are you sure that `:call TwiddleCase(%)` would work if you call it interactively?

Comment: It would be helpful to show `TwiddleCase`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble There ya go!

Comment: I posted an answer that corrects an obvious omission in your command line but I don't think the function call is correct. What you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: @BLayer I'm trying to twiddle the case between Proper-Case and UPPER CASE.

And I realize that the function just jumps between three states Proper, Upper and Lower.

Comment: @leeand00 As long as the external profile (type of return value and params) doesn't change then there should be no impact on the proper application of it...which is what the answer should be focused on, right? So did I make the proper assumptions about that aspect of it? If not, please update your answer with whatever additional details are relevant. (If you have questions about the function's actual logic then it would be best to open a new question for that.)

Comment: @BLayer Thank you for your answer!  I’ve been busy at work and just haven’t had the chance to try it out.  I will.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, the first command (`:call TwiddleCase(%)`) is missing the `+` (or `-c`) that must precede all commands.

And you shouldn't need that trailing `cat`.

Oh and stylistically, IMO, it's a little clearer to keep the `+`s outside the command-enclosing quotes.

So...

```
echo "110511093 some dude" | vim -es +'call TwiddleCase(%)' +'%print' +':q!' /dev/stdin
```

**HOWEVER**, there is something wrong with your approach. I'm not sure `%` is doing what you expect. I asked you about it in a comment and I'll update this answer as needed.

If I had to guess, based on "pass the buffer" and use of the `%print` command, you want to run the buffer's contents through your function and then replace the buffer with that. That requires a lot more than what you have. For your example the function call would be something like...

```
call setline(1, TwiddleCase(getline(1)))
```

If your real world case involves multiple lines then you could use the `g[lobal]` command to do something like the above against every non-empty line:

```
g/./ call setline(".", TwiddleCase(getline(".")))
```

Also, where is `TwiddleCase` defined? Because `vim -e` doesn't look for a vimrc like `vim` does. You could load your personal vimrc using `-u ~/.vimrc` (*nix style). Otherwise, you'll have to do something like `+ 'source {file}'` before the other `+` params, where `{file}` is a path to a file containing the `TwiddleCase` code.

So here's what the complete Vim invocation would look like if my assumptions are correct:

```
vim -es -u ~/.vimrc +'g/./ call setline(".", TwiddleCase(getline(".")))' +'%print' +':q!' /dev/stdin
```

Comment: I am still confused with the fact you all can call a function like that -- it gives me `Invalid expression: "%)"`

Comment: @MaximKim Check out the comment I just posted. I agree that something ain't right here. (OTOH, I do not get that error message...even with `-s` removed.)

Comment: @MaximKim Ah, you mean when run interactively, I suppose. Yes, I get that. It's obviously syntatically wrong. I'm guessing they mean "all buffer lines" though they're off track there.

Comment: I didn't know that `.vimrc` isn't loaded with `vim -e`

Comment: Yes, though strangely I can't find explicit/correct mention in the help docs. I see under `:h vimrc`,  _If Vim was started in Ex mode with the "-s" argument [normal vimrc search doesn't happen]_. But my testing show it's the same with or without "-s". ("started in Ex mode" is when you run `vim -e` or, alternatively, `ex`.)